# XML remove elements with jQuery where text is not equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Here is an example of my Xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
        <generator>SomeOne</generator>
        <item>
            <title>
                Some Item Title
            </title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
            <description>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </description>
            <pubDate>1/1/17 00:00:00</pubDate>
            <category>Cat1</category>
            <category>Cat2</category>
        </item>
        ....
        ....
        ....
    </channel>
</rss>
```

This is the code I have tried (`rss` is equal to `$('my xml data')`):

```
var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item').find('category').find(':not(:contains('+ myCat +'))').parent().remove();
```

There is no error, but it returns empty(in the console) and doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're using the `:not` in another `find()`, which won't work as you're already at the level of the `category` elements. There's no children to filter through. You need to combine those two selectors. Any of the following will work:

```js
// #1
var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item').find('category:not(:contains('+ myCat +'))').parent().remove();

// #2
var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item').find('category').filter(':not(:contains('+ myCat +'))').parent().remove();

// #3
var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item:has(category:not(:contains('+ myCat +')))').remove();

// #4
var myCat = 'Cat1';
rss.find('item').find('category').not(':contains('+ myCat +'))').parent().remove();
```

There's probably more, but hopefully you get the idea.